# get the list of checkbox post in django views

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this code in my template:

```
{% for email in emails %}
  {%if email%}
     <input type="checkbox" name="email" value="{{email}}" /> {{email}}<br />
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

so the output in the template is:

```
email1@sample.com
email2@sample.com
email3@sample.com
...
```

in my views I printed my request.POST about this.

```
print request.POST
print request.POST['email']
for email in request.POST['email']:
 print email
```

i got this output:

```
<QueryDict: {u'email': [u'email1@sample.com', u'email2@sample.com', u'email3@sample.com'], ..., u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'05e5bdb542c3be7515b87e8160c347a0', u'05e5bdb542c3be7515b87e8160c347a0']}>
email3@sample.com
e
m
a
i
l
3
@
s
a
m
p
l
e
.
c
o
m
```

my question is, how can I get the list of emails in my views?
I wanted the output will be like this..

```
email1@sample.com
email2@sample.com
email3@sample.com
...
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [request.POST.getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

> Returns the data with the requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value provided is not a list.

Comment: More specifically, `for email in request.POST.getlist('email')`

Comment: @burhan Yes, but I think reading some docs and writing that line yourself is more helpful than copy-pasting it.

Comment: I agree (which is why I +1 your answer initially), but for the sake of completely I added it.