# How to get information from one Django models object?

Tags: python, django

today I'm trying to get and print all my users emails, who had chose selection "Value1".

This is how my model.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class Vartotojas(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    option = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from emailai.models import Vartotojas

class VartotojasForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('Value1','Value1'),('Value2','Value2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    
    def save(self):
        mymodel = Vartotojas(
        email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
        option=self.cleaned_data['my_field'],
        )
        mymodel.save()
```

And finally my views.py "

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from emailai.models import Vartotojas
from renginiai.forms import VartotojasForm

def name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VartotojasForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = Vartotojas.objects.filter(option="u'Value1'") # How to do it right?
            # Now How To Get those object emails?
            new_user = form.save()
            return render(request, "Vartotojas-result.html", {
        'form': form, #BLABLABLA,
    })
    else:
        form = VartotojasForm()
    return render(request, "Vartotojas-form.html", {
        'form': form,
    })
```

I commented my questions inside my views.py. I hope you will be able to help me. Thank you in advance!

---

I re-write my code with getlist. Now it looks like this:

## views.py :

```
if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            option = request.POST.getlist('my_field')
            new_user = form.save(email, option)
```

forms.py:

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('Value1','Value1'),('Value2','Value2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    
    def save(self, email, option):
        mymodel = Vartotojas(
        email=email,
        option = option,
        )
        mymodel.save()
```

As you see I pasted just most important places. By the way, users can choose 2 values, that's why I use checkbox. But still it not working.

Comment: ur filtering all values with option='Value1' right? now u have list of objects that satisfy the option. u can loop over that list and get the email attribute by using the dot operator for example, a[i].email where i is the index of the list a.

Comment: And how to print it to the template?

Comment: You would have to add it to the dictionary you're passing to `render`, but don't do what the comment suggests; my answer below will give you the list directly and save the loop.

Comment: `option="u'Value1'"` looks very strange. You don't mean just `option=u'Value1'`?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, but still - it not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use the [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) property like so:

```
Vartotojas.objects.filter(option=u"Value1").values_list("email", flat=True)
```

to get a list of all email addresses. You may also want to apply a `distinct()` to that if you're not already preventing duplicates. On a side note, look into [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform): it looks like that would save you a fair bit of the time/ code you have written for dealing with this. You could create a ModelForm based on your `Vartotojas` object and not have to write the explicit `save()` method you have.

Comment: Thanks, you get me on the way. However, somewhere is mistake. In my opinion: option="u'Value1'". I think, i have to write "u'Value1'" somehow different, because now I get empty list, but I know that in it should be atleast 5 emails.

Comment: Sorry, I should have caught that: you want the `u` on the outside of the string, not inside it. I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) adds `DISTINCT` to the query, which is standard SQL and supported in all the databases Django typically works with.

Comment: Open your database table and see if there are records with that value in them. It might be helpful to play with the query filtering in the [Django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) rather than trying to figure it out in the view. Alternatively, you can try using [pdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb) and a breakpoint to debug the problem.

Comment: Using the shell, it would be good to find out if `Vartotojas.objects.filter(option=u"Value1")` returns any records. Also try it without the `u`, `Vartotojas.objects.filter(option="Value1")`

Comment: mhm it returns empty list, but in my admin interface I have objects with value1

http://www.part.lt/perziura/5df19523db16eb221991da731d7a8dd9392.png

Comment: Ah, no you don't: you have a record with a list in it. I'm guessing `self.cleaned_data['my_field']` refers to checkboxes in the form. If they are checkboxes with the same name, Django will organize that into a list. To properly handle the checkboxes, you'd want [getlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276753/get-the-list-of-checkbox-post-in-django-views), but I think you may want to change to radio buttons on the front-end if users are only supposed to select one.