# django: build admin-like checkbox returning queryset of selected items

Tags: django

sorry if title doesn't make lots of sense. What I would like to have is this:
[image]

Right now I have a model overview view looks pretty much like this but I am wondering how should I implement the circled part. Ideally it would be just like in admin, your selection results in a queryset containing those item you selected. I know probably some javascript magic could do this job but since it is already in admin, I am wondering if there is a more django-ish way to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you give every checkbox a value with the item's id and put them in an array you can use the following query:

```
list_of_ids = array of selected ids
objects = ObjectClass.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
```

---

### Html code:

```
<form>
  {% for object in objects %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="object_list" value="{{object.id}}" />
    <!-- more stuff -->
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit"> do stuff </button>
</form>
```

### View:

```
def do_stuff(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('object_list')
    objects = ObjectClass.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
```

Comment: I am sorry could you please elaborate a bit this more? I mean, the code you put there make sense but I am just not sure how to implement the template part. Right now I can think of calling a javascript whenever checkbox is checked to set, say, an Boolean array of which box is checked, but how would I take that array from templates back to view and do the filtering?

Comment: added an example, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276753/get-the-list-of-checkbox-post-in-django-views

Comment: Thanks so much! Just a minor thing, I would like the change to be in effect every time a box is checked without having to go through the submit and POST process. I guess I have to use javascript for that right?

Comment: pretty much, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a custom admin action like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages

# define admin action
def get_queryset_choices_from_queryset(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    # in that case we'll simply get only IDs
    queryset_choices = list(queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True))

    print('queryset_choices', queryset_choices)

    modeladmin.message_user(
        request,
        '[get_queryset_choices_from_queryset] Your choices --> {queryset_choices} and its count --> {queryset_choices_count}'.format(
            queryset_choices=queryset_choices,
            queryset_choices_count=queryset.count(),
        ),
        level=messages.SUCCESS
    )


get_queryset_choices_from_queryset.short_description = 'get_queryset_choices_from_queryset'

# register admin action
admin.site.add_action(get_queryset_choices_from_queryset)
```