# List with checked checkboxes in Django

Tags: python, html, django

So, i want to get the checked checkboxes items ids as a list and show them on another page. But when i get to that specific page i get the value 'None' instead of the list of ids. What could go wrong? I tried some different versions from another questions already posted on the site, but the result was the same.

Here is the code:

- models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class afirmatii(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

- views.py:

```
def exam(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checks = request.POST.get('selected[]')
        request.session['checks2'] = checks

    context = {
        'title' : 'Title1',
        'aff': afirmatii.objects.order_by('id')
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/exam.html', context)


def result(request):
    checks = request.session.get('checks2')
    context = {
        'title' : 'Title2',
        'checks': checks
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/result.html', context)
```

- exam.html:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="text-break">
    <form action="{% url 'result' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for q in aff %}
        <div class="border mb-3 rounded-sm bg-light p-2">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-info">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{ q.id }}" name = "selected[]">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ q.id }}" name = 'selected[]'> {{ q.text }} </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-info">Next</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

- result.html:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <p class="pb-5"> {{ checks }} </p><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-info" type="button">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-info" type="button">Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get the list of checkbox post in django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276753/get-the-list-of-checkbox-post-in-django-views)

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" ... name = "selected[]">` When the form is submitted, all the checkboxes will be named `selected[]`, and your code won't be able to tell them apart.

Comment: @JohnGordon so that means i have to write them one-by-one?

Comment: Presumably you can use some loop element to build unique names for each checkbox.

Comment: @SebastianTutuianu which view will be call first?

Comment: @MKPatel the 'exam' one

Comment: @JohnGordon I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use [FORMSETS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) A formsets is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the same page.

You can paint the list of questions according to records in the table and get ids (or other fields) of the marked answers

> **forms.py**

```
class ExamForm(forms.Form):

    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

> **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import formset_factory
from .forms import *


def exam(request):

    aff = afirmatii.objects.order_by('id')

    exam_formset = formset_factory(ExamForm, extra=0)

    formset = exam_formset(initial=[{'id': x.id, 'text': x.text} for x in aff])

    checks = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = exam_formset(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.forms:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('checkbox', None):
                    checks.append(form.cleaned_data)

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        'checks': checks,
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/exam.html', context)
```

> **exam.html**

```
{% if not checks %}

  <h1>Exam:</h1>
  <form action="{% url 'exam' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset.forms %}

      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.checkbox }}
        {{ form.text.value }}
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.text }}
      </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>

{% else %}

  <h1>Results:</h1>

  {% for check in checks %}
    <p>{{ check.id }} {{ check.text }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```